# Sphere rendering inside out using QGIS on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, 3d, ubuntu, 3d-map

I'm trying to use QGIS to show earthquakes around a 3d globe. I changed my CRS to 'Sphere_Van_der_Grinten_I' and it rendered like this:

[image: QGIS 3D render error]

Here's a report from Hardinfo on my system and display:

- Processor:    12x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz
- Memory:   65809MB (10399MB used)
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Resolution    1920x1080 pixels
- OpenGL Renderer:  Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
- X11 Vendor:   The X.Org Foundation

Updating my OpenGL renderer doesn't seem to have done anything; this screenshot is unchanged before and after I did `apt-get install mesa-utils`

How do I make this sphere work?

Comment: this is probably a projection issue, rather than a graphics card issue. what version of qgis? Although the world map LOOKS like a vector layer, is it actually a raster layer? (I've seen similar issues with raster layers and know how to fix these)

Comment: It might help to use `Save As ...`  for all layers to reproject to the target CRS and a different file name instead of relying on On-the-fly-reprojection.